# Hibernate / HQL query - is it possible to return entity and update additional field in entity

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

I have entities as:

**Student:**

- Id
- tuitionId
- dateJoined
- additionalField ← this field does not exist as a column in table Student

**Address:**

- mailing1
- zip
- id

My createQuery is currently for hibernate/hql:

select stu from Student as stu where id = ‘1’

I would like to change this so I can have the Address’s mailing1 populated into the stu entity’s additionalField.  Could I do something in hibernate hql that would look something like this:

**select stu,  (select mailing1 from Address where id=’1’ as additionalField ) from Student as stu where id = ‘1’**

Would this/modification of this be able to return the stu entityobject and the additionalField from the select clause’s 2nd selection from Address?  Appreciate your help, thanks!

Comment: `SELECT stu,
     (SELECT mailing1
   FROM   Address A
   WHERE  A.id = stu.id) AS additionalField
 FROM   Student AS stu
 WHERE  id = '1'`
or `SELECT stu.stu,
     a.mailing1 AS additionalField
 FROM   Student AS stu
     JOIN Address A
    ON A.id = stu.id
 WHERE  A.id = '1' `

Comment: How can the select be modified so that mailing1 is actually populated into stu?  So that we can just say "select stu FROM...." but it would include stu.mailing1?